# How in Termux to kill a process by PID when this process is running non-stoppable, e.g. vim after a typo cannot be closed?

Tags: termux

In my case it often happens that vim becomes non-operatable, does not accept key-strokes nor mouse actions and cannot be closed.

When vim runs in bash in one of the many windows below Konsole in  KDE/Kubuntu, I can switch to another window and can kill vim by

```
kill -9 PID
```

How to do such kill when vim runs in a single instance of Termux?

---

Some more details:

I have done:

```
:!ps
```

And I have seen the PID of vim.

Then I typed

```
:!kill -9 PID
```

Result: this instance of vim with this PID was killed, but automatically an new vim process was invoked with a new PID.

Now I thought, I have to stop this procedure, and I gave

```
:!kill -SIGSTOP PID
```

Result: all was dead.